# get value 1 - 2 - 1 - 2 - 1 in for loop php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I am trying to get value like 1-2-1-2-1-2 from for loop

I tried code like this

```
$c = count($response['video']); // 2
$currentPage  = 2;
$k = 1;
for ($i=$k; $i <= $currentPage ; $i++) {
    $b = $i > $c ? $k : $i;
    $urls = $response['video'][$b - 1];
    echo "$b";
}
```

where $currentPage = 5;  $c =2;

when $c = 3;  the value should be 1-2-3-1-2-3
when i echo $b or dd($b) out of loop i will got 12111 but i need answer 121212
please help me to solve this.

Comment: Totally unclear. What is $currentPage and $c for? Also, avoid the word _remember_. You aren't dictating us but rather telling us the different testcases.

Comment: @nice_dev see i updated my quetion

Comment: _when $c = 3; the value should be 1-2-3-1-2-3_ Ok, but how many times? Why not 1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3-1-2-3 ?

Comment: @nice_dev  upto $currentPage. when $currentPage = 5; it will 12312

Comment: @nice_dev when $currentPage = 4 it will start from 1 when $currentPage =  5 it will give 2... if 6 then 3 .. again 7 then 1  ... i hope you understand

Comment: you could use modulo 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$k = 1;
$currentPage = 5;
$c = 3;
for ($b=$i=$k; $i <= $currentPage ; $i++, $b++) {
    $b = $b <= $c ? $b : 1;
    echo $b;
}
```